# Find the unique values of a named vector with their corresponding names

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

As the tittle reveals I would like to find out  the unique values of a named vector with their corresponding names

```
library(dplyr)
temp <-   runif(10000, 0, 10) %>% ceiling() %>% as.integer()
names(temp) <-  c('a', 'b', "c", 'd', 'e','f', 'g', "s", "s", 'r') %>% rep(100)
```

The first 10 values of the named vector look like this.

```
temp[1:10]
a b c d e f g s s r 
7 4 9 2 5 7 9 8 8 8
```

I could find the unique values or the unique names. But I do not know how to find both of them and know how to match them.

```
temp %>% unique()
names(temp) %>% unique()
```

Comment: You mean `temp[unique(names(temp))]`?

Comment: What is the expected for first 10 values?

Comment: @Sotos Yes, Actually this is what I was looking for. Kind of simple but it slipped of my thoughts. Thanks. You can write it down as an answer and I will accept it, so we can finalllize the post

Comment: Not sure what we are trying to do, if we are matching on unique name the result will give you the first match, try: `x <- c(1,2,3); names(x) <- c("a", "a", "b"); x[unique(names(x))]` This will give `1,3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For named vectors you can simply do,

```
temp[unique(names(temp))]

#or

temp[!duplicated(names(temp))]

#or

temp[match(unique(names(temp)), names(temp))]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off making the names and the values separate columns in a data frame.  You can then use `distinct` to get the unique combinations.

```
library(dplyr)
temp <-   c(7, 4, 9, 2, 5, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8)
names(temp) <-  c('a', 'b', "c", 'd', 'e','f', 'g', "s", "s", 'r') 

data.frame(temp = temp[1:10],
           temp_name = names(temp[1:10])) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Comment: Now we need to convert it back to a named vector?

Comment: Given that the names of the vector are not unique, it seems strange to be using a names attribute on the vector at all.  It's rare that a named vector is more useful than two columns in a data frame.  The only time I can think of that I've _really_ needed a named vector is when defining select lists in `shiny`.

Comment: if you want it anyway, just add `%>% {setNames(.$temp,.$temp_name)}`